# What response code corresponds in REST API to not finding a resource due to query params?

Tags: api, rest, query-string

I found in my job that people are designing a RESTs API that has endpoints that return a single Json object (not a collection) based in query params (not path param).
For example:

```
/users?name=John&surname=Sparrow
```

with response body

```
{id:10, name="John", surname="Sparrow", gender="male"}
```

But what response code corresponds in REST API to not finding a resource due to query params?
For example:

```
/users?name=John&surname=Smith
```

(when John Smith doesn't exist).

I don't think it is a 404 error because /users endpoint exists, but I don't know if I must return a 400 error or a 200 without body (or null value) or other kind of response

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: its still a 404 IMO, or maybe a 204.

Answer (score 0):

What is most appropriate depends on whether an empty result list is OK or a clear failure. Whether parameters are PathParams or QueryParams has no bearing on return codes.

My general approach is that search functions such as findStuffBySearchTerms always return a successful HTTP code such as 200 and either the results or an empty list. On the other hand, fetchStuffById where I expect the entity to be found will return HTTP 404 if it is not found.

Answer (score 0):

> What response code corresponds in REST API to not finding a resource due to query params?

[404 Not Found](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).

> I don't think it is a 404 error because /users endpoint exists,

The resource identifier includes the query params.  Which is to say, the query parameters are part of the identifier in precisely the same sense that path segments are part of the identifier.

In your request *body*, you can describe the circumstances of your implementation as precisely as you like.

But the audience of HTTP status codes includes *general purpose* components (browsers, proxies, web crawlers), for whom the response code is the primary mechanism for describing the semantics of the response:

> The status-code element is a 3-digit integer code describing the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's corresponding request.  The rest of the response message is to be interpreted in light of the semantics defined for that status code. -- [RFC 7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)

---

That said, your server owns its own resources, and therefore you get to decide whether or not a resource exists, and what it's current representation looks like.

```
GET /users?name=Dave HTTP/1.1
```

```
200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

Dave's not here, man.
```

From an HTTP/REST framing, that's a perfectly reasonable exchange; somebody asked for the latest representation of `/users?name=Dave`, and the latest representation is a plain text document.  Absolutely fine.

The key idea here is that that HTTP status-code is metadata of the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain.

HTTP is indifferent to the semantic meaning of the representations of resources.

---

*That* said, you should be considering in your design concerns like "what does this look like in our access logs?"  If you want your operators to be able to distinguish this case from the similar case where the query parameters match information in your database, 200 vs 404 is the natural way to do that.

You'll normally prefer 404 to the other error status codes for this case because 404 indicates the response is cacheable, which is probably want you want when you are passed a request-target that has a spelling error in it somewhere.

Comment: With the 200 approach you have to implement extra checks client side if you can deserialize the response body to a user or not. It's not that nice, I think.